# Has the Control.Monad.State API changed recently?

Tags: haskell, state-monad

As a learning exercise, I'm trying to implement a heapsort in Haskell. I figured the `State` monad would be the right choice to do this, since heaps rely pretty heavily on moving data around inside a single structure (and `do` notation would be useful). Besides, I'm looking to cement my understanding of monads in general.

The [examples on the `State` monad](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more#state) in *Learn You A Haskell* (and a [number](http://brandon.si/code/the-state-monad-a-tutorial-for-the-confused/) of [other](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Advanced_monads#The_State_monad) [tutorials](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/monads.html#id643643)), say that `State` is defined as:

```
newtype State s a = State { runState :: s -> (a,s) }
```

I should be passing a function of type `s -> (a,s)` (which may or may not be curried in other arguments) to the `State` value constructor. So my functions look like this:

```
pop :: Ord a => State (Heap a) a
pop = State pop'
pop' :: Ord a => Heap a -> (a, Heap a)
-- implementation of pop' goes here

push :: Ord a => a -> State (Heap a) ()
push item = State $ push' item
push' :: Ord a => a -> Heap a -> ((), Heap a)
-- implementation of push' goes here
```

This doesn't compile, with the following error:

```
Not in scope: data constructor `State'
Perhaps you meant `StateT' (imported from Control.Monad.State)
```

From reading the [API docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html) for `Control.Monad.State`, it looks as though the `State` value constructor has been removed from the module since these tutorials were written. As a beginner, I find the documentation to be far from self-explanatory. So my question is:

1. Am I right in believing that the `State` value constructor is gone?
2. What should I be using instead?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Yes, it's gone, replaced by [`StateT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html#t:StateT). (The `State` monad is now defined in terms of the `StateT` monad transformer.)
2. You should be using the [`state`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html#v:state) function instead.

I would question whether your approach is correct, however. Instead of worrying about how `State` is implemented, consider using do-notation and the `get` and `put` functions.

Comment: Is `state` a drop-in replacement for `State`? Or do I need to declare an instance of `MonadState` for my data structure before it'll work?

Comment: `state` is a drop-in replacement for `State` as you are using it, yes. `State (Heap a)` is what needs to be an instance of `MonadState`, and it already is.

Comment: What is the recommended style for your suggestion of using `do` notation with `get` and `put`? Should I define most of my low-level functions non-monadically (for example: `push :: Ord a => a -> Heap a -> Heap a`), and then build a stateful computation out of these in a `do` block using lots of `let` bindings? Or should `push` and `pop` (or, at a lower level, my tree-traversal routines) be monadic functions that can be sequenced directly in a `do` block?

Answer (score 12):

Here are the correct implementations of the examples shown in the book related to State Monad:

MONADIC STACK:

```
-- MonadicStack.hs (Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!)

import Control.Monad.State  

type Stack = [Int]

pop :: State Stack Int
-- The following line was wrong in the book:
-- pop = State $ \(x:xs) -> (x,xs)  
pop = do
 x:xs <- get
 put xs
 return x

push :: Int -> State Stack ()  
-- The following line was wrong in the book:
-- push a = State $ \xs -> ((),a:xs)
push a = do
 xs <- get
 put (a:xs)
 return ()

pop1 = runState pop [1..5]
push1 = runState (push 1) [2..5]

stackManip :: State Stack Int  
stackManip = do  
 push 3  
 a <- pop  
 pop  

stackManip1 = runState stackManip [5,8,2,1]  
stackManip2 = runState stackManip [1,2,3,4]  

stackStuff :: State Stack ()  
stackStuff = do  
 a <- pop  
 if a == 5  
  then push 5  
  else do  
   push 3  
   push 8  

stackStuff1 = runState stackStuff [9,0,2,1,0]  
stackStuff2 = runState stackStuff [5,4,3,2,1]

moreStack :: State Stack ()  
moreStack = do  
 a <- stackManip  
 if a == 100  
  then stackStuff  
  else return ()  

moreStack1 = runState moreStack [100,9,0,2,1,0]
moreStack2 = runState moreStack [9,0,2,1,0]

stackyStack :: State Stack ()  
stackyStack = do  
 stackNow <- get  
 if stackNow == [1,2,3]  
  then put [8,3,1]  
  else put [9,2,1]  

stackyStack1 = runState stackyStack [1,2,3]
stackyStack2 = runState stackyStack [10,20,30,40]
```

MONADIC RANDOM GENERATORS:

```
-- MonadicRandomGenerator.hs (Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!)

import System.Random  
import Control.Monad.State  

randomSt :: (RandomGen g, Random a) => State g a  
-- The following line was wrong in the book:
-- randomSt = State random
randomSt = do
 gen <- get
 let (value,nextGen) = random gen
 put nextGen
 return value

randomSt1 = (runState randomSt (mkStdGen 1)) :: (Int,StdGen)
randomSt2 = (runState randomSt (mkStdGen 2)) :: (Float,StdGen)

threeCoins :: State StdGen (Bool,Bool,Bool)  
threeCoins = do  
 a <- randomSt  
 b <- randomSt  
 c <- randomSt  
 return (a,b,c)  

threeCoins1 = runState threeCoins (mkStdGen 33)
threeCoins2 = runState threeCoins (mkStdGen 2)

-- rollDie and rollNDice are not explained in the book LYAHFGG. 
-- But these functions are interesting and complementary:

rollDie :: State StdGen Int
rollDie = do 
 generator <- get
 let (value, newGenerator) = randomR (1,6) generator
 put newGenerator
 return value

rollDie1 = runState rollDie (mkStdGen 1)
rollDie2 = runState rollDie (mkStdGen 2)

rollNDice :: Int -> State StdGen [Int]
rollNDice 0 = do
 return []
rollNDice n = do
 value <- rollDie
 list <- rollNDice (n-1)
 return (value:list)

rollNDice1 = runState (rollNDice 10) (mkStdGen 1)
rollNDice2 = runState (rollNDice 20) (mkStdGen 2)
```

Answer (score 4):

I think `state` makes for a succinct implementation of `pop`, but `modify` is better for `push` since it returns unit:

```
import Control.Monad.State  

type Stack a = [a]

pop :: State (Stack a) a
pop = state $ \(a:as) -> (a, as)

push :: a -> State (Stack a) ()  
push a = modify (a:)
```

Answer (score 2):

DESUGARED MONADIC STACK:

```
-- DesugaredMonadicStack.hs (Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!)

import Control.Monad.State  

type Stack = [Int]

pop :: State Stack Int  
pop = 
 get >>=
 \(x:xs) -> put xs >>
 return x

push :: Int -> State Stack ()
push a =
 get >>=
 \xs -> put (a:xs) >>
 return ()

pop1 = runState pop [1..5]
push1 = runState (push 1) [2..5]

stackManip :: State Stack Int  
stackManip =
 push 3 >>
 pop >>=
 \a -> pop

stackManip1 = runState stackManip [5,8,2,1]  
stackManip2 = runState stackManip [1,2,3,4]  

stackStuff :: State Stack ()  
stackStuff =
 pop >>=
 \a -> 
  if a == 5 then
   push 5
  else
   push 3 >>
   push 8

stackStuff1 = runState stackStuff [9,0,2,1,0]  
stackStuff2 = runState stackStuff [5,4,3,2,1]

moreStack :: State Stack ()  
moreStack =
 stackManip >>=
 \a ->
  if a == 100 then
   stackStuff
  else
   return ()

moreStack1 = runState moreStack [100,9,0,2,1,0]
moreStack2 = runState moreStack [9,0,2,1,0]
moreStack3 = runState moreStack [100,5,4,3,2,1]

stackyStack :: State Stack ()  
stackyStack =
 get >>=
 \stackNow ->
  if stackNow == [1,2,3] then
   put [8,3,1]
  else
   put [9,2,1]

stackyStack1 = runState stackyStack [1,2,3]
stackyStack2 = runState stackyStack [10,20,30,40]
```

DESUGARED MONADIC RANDOM GENERATOR:

```
-- DesugaredMonadicRandomGenerator.hs (Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!)

import System.Random  
import Control.Monad.State  

randomSt :: (RandomGen g, Random a) => State g a  
randomSt =
 get >>=
 \gen -> 
  let (value,nextGen) = random gen
  in
   put nextGen >>
   return value

randomSt1 = (runState randomSt (mkStdGen 1)) :: (Int,StdGen)
randomSt2 = (runState randomSt (mkStdGen 2)) :: (Float,StdGen)

threeCoins :: State StdGen (Bool,Bool,Bool)
threeCoins =
 randomSt >>=
 \a -> randomSt >>=
 \b -> randomSt >>=
 \c -> return (a,b,c)

threeCoins1 = runState threeCoins (mkStdGen 33)
threeCoins2 = runState threeCoins (mkStdGen 2)

-- rollDie and rollNDice are not explained in the book LYAHFGG. 
-- But these functions are interesting and complementary:

rollDie :: State StdGen Int
rollDie =
 get >>=
 \generator -> 
  let (value, newGenerator) = randomR (1,6) generator
  in
   put newGenerator >>
   return value

rollDie1 = runState rollDie (mkStdGen 1)
rollDie2 = runState rollDie (mkStdGen 2)

rollNDice :: Int -> State StdGen [Int]
rollNDice 0 = return []
rollNDice n =
 rollDie >>=
 \value -> rollNDice (n-1) >>=
 \list -> return (value:list)

rollNDice1 = runState (rollNDice 10) (mkStdGen 1)
rollNDice2 = runState (rollNDice 20) (mkStdGen 2)
```